# Weird char (�) appears after doing html_entity_decode

Tags: php, html-encode

In a separate YML file i have :
 `flags:       [<img src="/images/cms_bo/icons/english.png" alt="English"/>]`

When i call this into my code, it's not interpreted, so i used `html_entity_decode`.

It works but i have only **1 strange char just before my image** : `�`

```
<?php echo html_entity_decode($form['lang']->render()); ?>
```

All my files are UTF8 encoded. Do you have an idea on what i've missed to solve this problem ?

PS:

```
      public static function getI18nCulturesForChoice()
  {
      return array_combine(self::getI18nCultures(), self::getI18nCulturesFlags());
  }
```

Comment: Showing some more relevant code will help

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Why do you use `html_entity_decode` in the first place? There are no entities in your description.

Comment: @jon @shakti because otherwise my code isn't interpreted. It doens't show the image but just the <img src="/images/cms_bo/icons/english.png" alt="English"/> (just the string)

Comment: How is the value being loaded from the YML file?

Comment: Can you pull the html that is rendered to the page to show us how the character has been encoded?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using `html_entity_decode($form['lang']->render(),ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");`

Comment: Thanks that's finally fixed it ;-)

Comment: Didn't worked for me. I am fetching from mysql table with collation UTF-8_GENERAL_CI. :(

Answer (score 1):

Prior to PHP 5.3.3, the *default character set* for [`html_entity_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) was **ISO-8859-1**!  If you're working with UTF-8, you will need to use the third argument to the function to tell it to deal with UTF-8 instead of assuming ISO-8859-1.

This is blindly assuming you're using an older version of PHP.

If you *are* using a newer version of PHP, consider using [`iconv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) with the `//IGNORE//TRANSLIT` flags to try and remove any bad UTF-8 sequences *before* passing the string into `html_entity_decode`.

Comment: @Charles Unfortunalty, it's a good lead, but i'm using php 5.3.3 :'(

Comment: I stealth-edited my post to deal with that possibility.  � is the "I can't represent that character" glyph, so clearly something is being lost somewhere...

Comment: Still not :'( , ( <?php echo html_entity_decode(iconv('UTF-8', '//IGNORE//TRANSLIT',$form['lang']->render())); ?> )

Comment: What's the output of `rawurlencode($form['lang']->render())`, please?  Sounds like it's time to inspect the bytes.

Comment: @Charles sorry for the delay, here are the result of rawurlencode : http://pastie.org/1673679

Comment: That solution happens to be the same one I posted here.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your file has a Byte Order Mark (BOM) set.

Comment: i don't think so because without html_entity_decode, it outputs the string as it really is. Without weird char

Comment: and I use textmate : (By default in Textmate for the Mac, it creates UTF-8 files without any BOM markers. )